How does increasing Al2O3 in sodium silicate glass in a pH electrode allow it to respond more to Na+, Li+ and K+ making to less specific towards H+
The sodium silicate glass of a pH electrode is made by fusing Al2O3, Na2O and SiO2. If you increase the concentration of Al2O3, why do the glass respond more to ions like Na+, Li+ and K+ instead of H+. My guess is that there is more ion exchange site since 2 Al is bonded to 3 oxygen allowing more cations to bond with the glass surface, am I on the right track? Its on my lecture slides without elaboration. Wish I could ask my prof but I would have to wait until school term starts.

I heard once that pH electrode is made by adding some lanthanum $\ce{La}$ to the  usual glass.

There is addition of Li2O.

Ya I did see some sources using Li2O in the glass membrane but it still does not really explain how Al2O3 in glass reduce the specificity of the glass membrane to H+ ions. Looking at the table of electronegativity, all the molecules are pretty polar. the difference is the number of oxygen attached. Maybe having more oxygen atom in Al2O3 means more electronegative site? But that is just my hypothesis, I am not sure which is why i asked

These oxides are not molecular substances.
